Нужны ли зaпятые?
1. Ты это сделаешь, неизвестно(,) как оправдываясь перед семьёй.
2. Ты это сделаешь, без понятия(,) как оправдываясь перед семьёй.
Подскажите, пожалуйста, нужны ли запятые на месте пропусков в двух вариантах этого предложения?

Правильно:
Ты это сделаешь, неизвестно как оправдавшись перед семьёй.
Пояснение

В данном случае используется деепричастие совершенного вида. Такое деепричастие обозначает законченное действие, которое предшествует действию,  обозначенному сказуемым. То есть оправдаешься, а потом сделаешь.

Грамота
 Деепричастия совершенного вида отвечают на вопрос что 
 сделав? и обозначают действие, предшествовавшее действию 
 основного глагола: Встав на табурет, он достал книгу с 
 верхней полки. 


Неизвестно как – цельное по смыслу наречное выражение, которое входит в деепричастный оборот.
Аналогично "без понятия как", но этот вариант по стилистике смотрится хуже.

Примечание. Вариант решения приведен для определенной семантики сообщения, но это можно уточнить только по контексту.

В первом предложении запятая не не нужна, "неизвестно" и как  это наречие и не выделяется запятыми,  а во втором предложении тоже не выделять запятой перед КАК здесь "как" каким образом- неизвестно как делать что-то.
